# How to dynamically show the component based on the state

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a dashboard where it has a sidebar, and that sidebar will change the state.

Here is how I do it

my showPage:

```
showPage(page) {
    switch (page) {
      case 'feeds':
        return <HelpPage />;
      case 'messages':
        return <MessagesPage />;
      case 'projects':
        return <ProjectsPage />;
      case 'support':
        return <SupportPage />;
      case 'about':
        return <AboutPage />;
      default:
        return <DialogPage />;
    }
  }
```

my render method:

How I switch the page:

```
handleClick(page) {
this.props.pageSwitcher(page);
} 
...
<ListItem
    primaryText="Feeds"
    onClick={() => this.handleClick("feeds")} />
```

How I call the element:

```
<Col xs={6} sm={6} md={6} lg={8}>
{
    this.showPage(page)
}
</Col>
```

My action:

```
export function pageSwitcher(page = '') {
  let payload = {};
  switch (page) {
    case 'feeds':
      payload = {
        type: types.SHOW_HELPS_FEED,
        page,
      };
      break;
    case 'messages':
      payload = {
        type: types.SHOW_INBOX,
        page,
      };
      break;
    case 'projects':
      payload = {
        types: types.SHOW_PROJECTS,
        page,
      };
      break;
    case 'support':
      payload = {
        types: types.SHOW_SUPPORT,
        page,
      };
      break;
    case 'about':
      payload = {
        types: types.SHOW_ABOUT,
        page,
      };
      break;
    default:
      payload = {
        types: '',
        page,
      };
  }
  return payload;
}
```

At the very beginning, it loads the default component `<DialogPage />`. But after I click the Feeds `ListItem`, it does not replace the `<DialogPage />` with the `<HelpPage />`. However I can see in Redux debugging tools that it calls the `componentWillMount` in the `HelpPage`.

How can I dynamically show the component based on the state?

Thanks!

EDIT: 
It works if in my `showPage` only returns a Component, but if I return a Container it won't display anything. It is because I have `componentWillMount` that calls an action, and the previous state for dashboard is being replaced.
Here is the reducer of my container that I want to load:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

export default function helpsReducer(state = {
  isFetching: false,
  items: [],
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.HELPS_FEED_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
      });
    case types.HELPS_FEED_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        items: [
          ...state.items,
          ...action.items,
        ],
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're not providing enough details where it matters. Strip the grid and most of your rendered items, and instead insert something else, like a pageSwitcher, etc. (See https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/asking-good-questions-421f08ee7e5c#.w1rhnxu9b) Also, a jsbin with the minimal version of your code could help others help you.

Comment: add your parent component where pageSwitcher method is there

Comment: @GoshaArinich I updated my question. I did what suggested, but apparently it wont show anything except an Component. That because if I switch to an container, somehow my state for the dashboard is empty again

Answer (score 1):

I have created simple example based on your question.

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/48038/

```js
var Child = React.createClass({
    renderPage: function (page) {
        if (page === 'one') {
            return <div>one</div>;
        }

        return <div>two</div>;
    },
    handleClick: function (page) {
        this.props.switchPage(page);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li 
                        style={{cursor: 'pointer', textDecoration: 'underline'}}
                        onClick={() => this.handleClick('one')}
                    >
                        one
                    </li>
                    <li
                        style={{cursor: 'pointer', textDecoration: 'underline'}}
                        onClick={() => this.handleClick('two')}
                    >
                        two
                    </li>
                    {this.renderPage(this.props.page)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {page: 'one'};
    },
    switchPage: function (page) {
        this.setState({page: page});
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child page={this.state.page} switchPage={this.switchPage}/>
            </div>  
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Parent />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: To clarify that, u dont actually need parent component, here is an example
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/48040/

Comment: it does not work if I return a Container. It works if only I return a Component.